# Calling a list of objects into an method to check for enum values

Tags: java, list, object, enums, return

im new to java and have a list of objects called `listPlayer` heres a sample

```
Player{FirstName='Marco', LastName='Reus', Team='Dortmund', Country='Germany', Fitness='Unfit', RecoveryTime='Slow'}
```

i also have an enum that values a range of fitness levels

```
public enum LevelOfFitness {
/**
 * Enum that represent the different level of Fitness of each player
 */

    CAREER_IN_DOUBT(8), INDEFINITELY_INJURED(7), INJURED(6), UNFIT(5), CLOSE_TO_FITNESS(4), 
NEAR_MATCH_FIT(3),
    MATCH_FIT(2), DATA_DEFICIENT(1), NOT_EVALUATED(0);

private int value;

LevelOfFitness (int aValue) {
    this.value = aValue;
}

public int getValue () {
    return value;
}
```

}

i also have a method that  loops to check if the name found in `listPlayer` is the same as the one found in the enum values.

```
public LevelOfFitness from(String value){  


  LevelOfFitness found = null;
  for(LevelOfFitness level : LevelOfFitness.values()){
      if(level.name().equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
         return level;
      }
  }

   throw new IllegalStateException("Not able to find fitness level for " + value);
}
```

im struggling to understand how to call this enum method into my main and call `listPlayer` into the loop so it can return a level of fitness.For example the first player to loop through check level (unfit) and return 5 as the level many thanks.

Comment: Where is declared this `from(String)` method? In which class?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your `from(String)` method is declared in `enum LevelOfFitness`.

You care make `from(String)` a `static` method, and call like: `LevelOfFitness.from("string");`;

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    List<Player> playerList = new ArrayList<>();
    playerList.add(new Player("Marco", "Reus", "Dortmund", "Germany", "Unfit", "Slow"));
    playerList.add(new Player("Name1", "Name2", "Team1", "Country1", "not_evaluated", "time1"));
    playerList.add(new Player("Name1", "Name2", "Team1", "Country1", "error_fitness", "time1"));
        
    for(Player player : playerList){

        try{

            LevelOfFitness lof = LevelOfFitness.from(player.getFitness());
            System.out.println(lof.getValue());

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}

----- output -----
5
0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not able to find fitness level for error_fitness
```

Comment: This is one of the issues im stuck on, im not too sure what my from(String) is meant to do, the idea is to push playerlist through it i believe

Comment: `from(String)` - Get a `String` as input. By iterating all declared values in `LevelOfFitness`, it tries to find if name of one(`CAREER_IN_DOUBT, UNFIT, ...`) of them matches with input. If there find a match, returns the `LevelOfFitness` which represents that name/value.